# How to make favicon to be shown in web page?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

All the static files appear except favicon whenever I refresh the page. I tried a lot made changes but didn't get the required result.

**index.html**

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'images/W.png' %}" type="image/png" sizes="16x16">
```

**settings.py**

```
import os.path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.conf.urls.static import static


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('app1.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**command prompt message**

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 20804
```

**Folder structure**

[image]

Comment: Do you see the request for the favicon in your devtools?

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: When you empty your cache and you have your browser's development tools open, preferably on the "network" tab and then request your site, what request and response do you see for your favicon?

Comment: Since the image URL can be opened without problem there is no issue in Django project configuration. In the previous instance of this question I gave you the link to one of discussions about favicon filetypes and so on. Does your browser want 16x16 size? Does it support PNG?

Comment: I am using chrome it supports png. My other images are also in png

Comment: But it's not showing me that favicon

Comment: Try validating your HTML: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: I have Django problem, not HTML.

Comment: I checked html in normal. It was working. Favicon was showing to me but in django it is not